# Undefined variable notice when appending to variable

Tags: php, list, download

I've a problem with a download script, everything is working as it should, it list all the items in the folder and I can download them, but I still get an error message. I tried to re-arrange the "" and '' but then I got some other weird mistakes.

Here is my error:

**Notice: Undefined variable: thelist in D:\xampp\htdocs\download_test\index.php on line 5**

Here is my code

```
 <?php
 if ($handle = opendir('downloads/')) {
   while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
          if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            $thelist .= '<li><a href="http://localhost/download_test/download.php?f=downloads/'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></li>';

          }
       }
  closedir($handle);
  }
?>
<h1>List of files:</h1>
<ul><?php echo $thelist; ?></ul>
```

Help would really be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize the variable first:

```
$thelist = "";
```

before your if clause.

The undefined error occurs when you first try to extend a not yet existing string.

Answer (score 3):

```
$thelist .= 'blah';
```

Is shorthand for

```
$thelist = $thelist . 'blah';
```

Even though you're trying to define $thelist at the start of the line (before the =), this depends on the latter part of the line executing first (= $thelist . 'blah') -- because you need to work out the value before you can store it in the variable. As you haven't said what $thelist is, though, PHP assumes that it's an empty variable.

As mentioned by bwoebi, you need to define $thelist to resolve this. Setting it to an empty value, i.e.

```
$thelist = '';
```

anywhere prior to your outer if clause should fix this.

Comment: +1 You're absolutely right; but I'd set it before the if clause as said in my answer as when you put it inside of the if body and your if fails, then the variable will also be undefined (in the echo later). (instead of only prior to the while loop)

Comment: I actually didn't think of that! Though, if the directory is empty, readdir() should still return '.' and '..'.

With that in mind, I believe it's cleaner to define it before the if anyway, rather than relying on '.' and '..' anyway, so I've updated my comment.

Comment: And what if the directory does even not exist? (or opendir fails for some other problem like no permissions etc.)

Comment: In this case, you're going to get a warning, which is more significant than the undefined error. That said, it remains cleaner to keep it outside of the if statement regardless.

Comment: Yes, it should be written `if ($handle = @opendir(...))` with adapted error handling in some else...

Answer (score 0):

Its just a notice, not an error. Its says that in a good code you should declare a variable first before using it. Your code will work fine though.